# Pricing an option with a certain payoff

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, pricing

Suppose an option with a payoff function

$$ \max((1+k)S_1,kS_2) $$ where $S_1, S_2$ are stock prices and $k>0$ is a constant value.

To value such an option, one would decompose this payoff function into plain vanilla options (and possibly bonds), as they can be valued using the Black-Scholes formula.

How can this payoff function be decomposed?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

$$\max(S_1, S_2) = S_1 + \max(S_2-S_1, 0)$$
In the case of GBM, the second term in the RHS can be valued using [Magrabe's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margrabe%27s_formula). The scalars $k, 1+k$ don't change this significantly.

Comment: I got $ (1+k)S_1 + max(kS_2-(1+k)S_1,0) $. 

Is it correct to price the part $max(kS_2-(1+k)S_1,0)$ by directly utilizing the Magrabe's formula, i.e.,  by simply plugging $kS_2$ and $(1+k)S_1$ into the Magrabe's formula?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes -- another kind of loose way of thinking of it is that in GBM,  having scalar multiple of a stock (instead of just one unit) is sort of the same as having a different initial stock price

Comment: You mentioned that the formula assumes GBM, how about if we have the dynamic $$ S_{ik} = S_{i0}*e^{(\mu_i-\frac{1}{2}(\sigma^2_{i,1}+\sigma^2_{i,2}))k+\sigma_{i,1}Z_{i,1}+\sigma_{i,2}Z_{i,2}}$$, where $i=1,2$?

Comment: I might be missing something but that appears to be lognormal also and so could come from a GBM as well